# Errors using <http:body> in EXPath HTTP Client

Tags: xslt, exslt

(first of all, please bear with me, this is my first time using the respective technologies; maybe this is a really simple error)

---

**Update:** I'm rephrasing the question as I know more about the issue now, and the problem is clearly on the EXPath side...

---

I'm trying to get a client made with XSLT + EXPath HTTP Client to talk to a server but I can't get the combination POST+`<http:body>` to work...

The following are mostly taken from real example code, but it's not easy to find an example which is directly applicable.

Here are some ressources I've used:

http://expath.org/modules/http-client/

http://expath.org/modules/http-client/samples

http://expath.org/spec/http-client

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-expath/

I'm using `expath-http-client-saxon-0.12.0`, btw.

Here's the code from the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:http="http://expath.org/ns/http-client"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                version="2.0">

   <xsl:import href="http://expath.org/ns/http-client.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template name="main" match="/">
      <root>
         <!-- the request element -->
         <xsl:variable name="request" as="element(http:request)">
            <http:request method="post" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/test">
              <http:body media-type="application/xml"/>
            </http:request>
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:variable name="body" as="element()">
           <x>1</x>
         </xsl:variable>
         <!-- sending the request -->
         <xsl:variable name="resp" select="http:send-request($request,(),$body)"/>
         <!-- add the http:response element to the output tree -->
         <xsl:sequence select="$resp[1]"/>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please forgive me if some things are redundant, I tried a real lot of variants of this.

I'm trying to test sending the request with Fiddler, as suggested by @MartinHonnen.

If I call the client with

```
saxon -xsl:post-example.xsl -it:main
```

then I get the message

```
May 15, 2016 10:53:42 AM org.expath.pkg.repo.tools.Logger info
INFO: Create a new repository with storage: File system storage in /usr/share/expath/repo
No license file found - running with licensable features disabled
2016/05/15 10:53:42:496 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888: Error serializing the body content
2016/05/15 10:53:42:499 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888
2016/05/15 10:53:42:499 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888: Error serializing the body content
2016/05/15 10:53:42:500 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888
2016/05/15 10:53:42:500 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888: Error serializing the body content
2016/05/15 10:53:42:500 CEST [INFO] DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request to {}->http://127.0.0.1:8888
Error on line 18 of post-example.xsl:
  Error sending the HTTP request
Error sending the HTTP request
```

I tried to understand how to configure serialization, but it's very complicated, and I don't really think the defaults should not cause problems with such a simple case?

Fiddler shows this:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_101)
```

but no body content.

It also gives numerous messages of the form

```
96  Failed to obtain request body. System.IO.InvalidDataException Bad request: Chunked Body was missing entirely.
```

I also tried this, with the same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:http="http://expath.org/ns/http-client"
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                version="2.0">

   <xsl:import href="http://expath.org/ns/http-client.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template name="main" match="/">
      <root>
         <!-- the request element -->
         <xsl:variable name="request" as="element(http:request)">
           <http:request method="post" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/test">
             <http:body media-type="text/plain">foo</http:body>
           </http:request>
         </xsl:variable>
         <!-- sending the request -->
         <xsl:variable name="resp" select="http:send-request($request)"/>
         <!-- add the http:response element to the output tree -->
         <xsl:sequence select="$resp[1]"/>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I find out what is going wrong?

PS: If anybody can suggest another tool for interfacing XSLT (Saxon) with a REST API I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: I am not familiar with those tools but if you have one tool like curl doing the right thing then perhaps as a debugging step it helps using a tool like fiddler to compare the HTTP requests and responses being exchanged when you use curl versus expath.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for the suggestion. If I interpret the result correctly, there is no body in the request (`Content-Length: 0`) Which still begs the question what I'm doing wrong in the body declaration for the http request...

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems simple enough: use `expath-http-client-saxon-0.11.0`.

The suggestion came from Adam Retter over at

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/expath

With that version it works.

So it seems version 0.12.0 is broken (currently).